# Entity Framework 6 - how to convert this line to async?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, async-await, entity-framework-6

I am wondering how do I change this statement to be async?

```
    var findBarCode = context.Barcodes
        .Where(x => x.Code == barcode)
        .Select(x => x.Product).FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't see like any `async where` statement I can use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about SingleAsync or FindAsync? Not sure about FirstOrDefault one

Do use await.

```
var findBarCode = await context.Barcodes
        .Where(x => x.Code == barcode)
        .SingleAsync(x => x.Product);
```

Another way (might silly as I have no access to VS at present):

```
 var findBarCode = await context.Barcodes
            .Where(x => x.Code == barcode)
            .OrderBy(YOURCRITERIA)
            .Take(1)
            .Select(x => x.Product)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: There's a `FirstOrDefaultAsync` and a `FirstAsync`.

Comment: These methods are hidden away in `System.Data.Entity`, so you might not see them right away in Intellisense.

Comment: Btw this namespace is in the `EntityFramework` assembly, so you will need to add reference to it in you project before you can use `System.Data.Entity`

Comment: @AFD Weird was doing exact same thing looking for a bar code thanks for this answer lol.

Answer (score 39):

There's an extension method called `FirstOrDefaultAsync` in `System.Data.Entity`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
...
var findBarCode = await context.Barcodes
    .Where(x => x.Code == barcode)
    .Select(x => x.Product).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This [requires Entity Framework 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220208%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that the extension method is in System.Data.Entity

Comment: I believe it's also only available if targeting net4.5. I had EF6 but needed to reinstall since it was installed when the project was targetting net4.0